# Keydown event does not seem to work

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm working on a reactiontest. When I copied my project into some other project (with a menu etc.) the timer and Keydown did not work. My friend solved the timer with a Eventhandler, but the keydown still does not work.

```
private void Button1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        char c = Convert.ToChar(e.KeyCode);
        if (c == 82)
        {
            this.BackColor = Color.LightBlue;
            extime.Stop();
            long rtime = extime.ElapsedMilliseconds;
            timer1.Enabled = false;
            button1.Text = Convert.ToString(rtime) + Environment.NewLine + "milliseconds";
            button1.Visible = true;
            extime.Reset();
        }
    }
```

this did not work:

```
private void Reactiontest_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        button1.KeyDown += Button1_KeyDown;
    }
```

Comment: Have you associated the `Button1_KeyDown` with the button? That is, `button1.KeyDown += Button1_KeyDown`.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried putting your keydown_event in the form instead of the button?